# p2-maven-plugin - "missing requirement" "requires 'java.package; javax.interceptor [1.2.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found"

Tags: java, maven, osgi, eclipse-rcp, p2

I have a large Eclipse RCP application with lots of transitive dependencies.

Currently, these are manually copied into the classpath but that's a significant administrative overhead I'd like to avoid, and would instead like to use [p2-maven-plugin](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin).

I've created a simple `pom.xml` based on the supplied example, that imports a Hibernate dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001 XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.reficio.rcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-p2-site</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.5.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
                <artifactId>p2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <id>org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.4.28.Final</id>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've compiled this to a local p2 repository using `mvn clean p2:site`.

And in my `target-platform.target` I've then referenced it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target includeMode="feature" name="Running Platform">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="file:/path/to/p2/target/repository/"/>
            <unit id="antlr" version="2.7.7"/>
            <unit id="com.fasterxml.classmate" version="1.5.1"/>
            <unit id="com.sun.istack.commons-runtime" version="3.0.7"/>
            <unit id="com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.FastInfoset" version="1.2.15"/>
            <unit id="javassist" version="3.27.0.GA"/>
            <unit id="javax.activation-api" version="1.2.0"/>
            <unit id="javax.persistence-api" version="2.2.0"/>
            <unit id="jaxb-api" version="2.3.1"/>
            <unit id="net.bytebuddy.byte-buddy" version="1.10.17"/>
            <unit id="org.dom4j" version="2.1.3"/>
            <unit id="org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime" version="2.3.1"/>
            <unit id="org.glassfish.jaxb.txw2" version="2.3.1"/>
            <unit id="org.hibernate.common.hibernate-commons-annotations" version="5.1.2.Final"/>
            <unit id="org.hibernate.entitymanager" version="5.4.28.Final"/>
            <unit id="org.hibernate.orm.core" version="5.4.28.Final"/>
            <unit id="org.jboss.jandex" version="2.2.3.Final"/>
            <unit id="org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging" version="3.4.1.Final"/>
            <unit id="org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction.jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec" version="1.1.1.Final"/>
            <unit id="org.jvnet.staxex.stax-ex" version="1.8.0"/>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>
```

But when I resolve this, I get this error:

```
Problems occurred while resolving the target contents
    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
        Cannot satisfy dependency:
            From: hibernate-core 5.4.28.Final (org.hibernate.orm.core 5.4.28.Final)
            To: java.package; javax.transaction [1.1.0,2.0.0)
        Missing requirement: Java Transaction API 1.1.1.Final (org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction.jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec 1.1.1.Final) requires 'java.package; javax.interceptor [1.2.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
        Software being installed: hibernate-core 5.4.28.Final (org.hibernate.orm.core 5.4.28.Final)
```

What am I missing, please?

Comment: The error message says, that the bundle/plugin `org.hibernate.orm.core 5.4.28.Final` has `Import-Package: javax.interceptor;version="[1.2.0,2.0.0)"`, but there is no bundle/plugin in your target platform that exports the package `javax.interceptor` of version >= 1.2 and < 2.0. Do you know the different concepts of `Require-Bundle` vs. `Import-Package`?

Comment: @howlger no, clearly I do not.

Comment: `Require-Bundle` is similar to Maven dependencies: an artifact tells which other artifacts of a certain version range it requires, which in turn may also require artifacts and so on. `Import-Package` is more powerful: an artifact tells which other packages of a certain version range it requires without telling in which artifacts those required packages are contained. `Import-Package` has the advantages, that versioning happens on package level and that this concept is independent of the decision in which artifact a required package is shipped.

Comment: @howlger do you have an example of how that could be used in my case? I can't see `Import-Package` or `Require-Bundle` in the target definition.

Comment: This is another difference to Maven. Since in Maven dependencies have to be resolved only at compile time, the dependencies are specified outside of the JAR in the `pom.xml`. In contrast, since in OSGi/Eclipse the dependencies have also to be resolved at runtime to install, start, stop and uninstall bundles/plugins, they are specified inside the JAR in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. The target definition just defines the pool from which the right bundles/plugins are picked. The Maven plugin Tycho can even build a plugin project without a `pom.xml`, which is called POM-less.